# Exact differential eqns and exact differential forms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any connection between exact differential equations and forms, or is the similarity in name just an accident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential equation

\begin{equation*}
I(x,y)dx + J(x,y)dy = 0
\end{equation*}

is exact is by definition the same as this differential being an exact form.